# Angularjs toaster not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using this library for angularjs toaster:

> https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster

and added the following references:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/AngularJS-Toaster/toaster.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/AngularJS-Toaster/toaster.min.js"></script>
```

I also added angular-animate as it seems using it, and added dependency injection on app module as:

```
 .module('venture', [
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'satellizer',
    'angularPayments',
    'angularFileUpload',
    'ngBootbox',
    'ui.tinymce',
    'ngSanitize',
    'pikaday',
    'ngAnimate',
    'toaster',
])
```

My controller parametes looks as:

```
.controller("ClassController", ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$state', 'ClassService', 'ERROR_MSG', 'SUCCESS_MSG', 'FileUploader', 'REST_END_POINT', '$stateParams', 'UserService', 'toaster',
        function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $timeout, $state, ClassService, ERROR_MSG, SUCCESS_MSG, FileUploader, REST_END_POINT, $stateParams, UserService, toaster) {
```

and somewhere on the code I am using:

```
toaster.pop('success', "title", "text");
```

I know it comes here the execution but the toaster never shows up, nor the error comes...

Just so you know I am using angualarjs 1.2.16
I donw know what I am missing out here?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't mention that you added

```
<toaster-container></toaster-container>
```

to index.html

Maybe that's it?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the toaster plugin your using:

> AngularJS-Toaster requires AngularJS v1.2.6 or higher and specifically
>   targets AngularJS, not Angular 2, although it could be used via
>   ngUpgrade.

Comment: so, are u saying there is no way I can use this library? Do you know any other toaster library for angularjs 1.2.16? thanks

Comment: what does the ngUpgrade means here?

Comment: The ngUpgrade statement is in regards to using this plugin with Angular 2. It's clear from the plugin documentation that it won't work with your version of Angular. I'm not aware of another package off the top of my head.